# How to integrate MS Teams in AEM?

Tags: aem, microsoft-teams

I want to notify some specific channels for specific events in MS Teams,

Some of the basic events,

When a page gets published
When a code is deployed or package is installed

I want to post a message in MS Teams if any one of the event happens in AEM instance. Do we have any connector or cloud service to integrate this in AEM?  Please share your thoughts and idea on how to integrate MS teams in AEM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this documentation to set up AEM with Adobe I/O events: https://www.adobe.io/events/docs/guides/using/aem/

Then configure your webhook in MS Teams:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors